# Работа в Linux на AWS EC2, нет apt-get

Tags: linux, apt-get, amazon-web-services

Моя задача развернуть на AWS Odoo 9. 
Я уже создал инстанс и подключился к нему через gitbash. Для начала установки Odoo 9. Мне необходимо воспользоваться `apt-get`. При наборе этой команды выводит сообщение `command not found`. Т.е. `apt-get` нет в Linux? Как его установить?

> `uname -a`

--

```
Linux ip-172-31-21-46 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Oct 24 01:31:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> ```
> sudo cat /etc/*-release
> ```

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09
```

Comment: дистрибутив-то какой?

Comment: Наберите в консоли `uname -a` и `sudo cat /etc/*-release` и приведите в вопросе вывод этих команд. В разных дистрибутивах разные версии менеджера пакетов, `apt-get` вполне может отсутствовать.

Comment: для справки. у программы linux вообще нет ни одной команды: это не интерпретатор, а специальная программа, выполняющая функции ядра операционной системы.

Comment: Тогда функция apt-get?

Comment: @RadoDuoistin, какой дистрибутив вы выбрали при создании виртуальной машины? если не помните, то приведите вывод команды `cat /etc/*release*`.

Comment: @alexander barakin Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по выводу команды `cat /etc/*release*`, вы выбрали виртуальную машину с дистрибутивом [fedora](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora), основанным на (и тесно с ним переплетающимся) дистрибутиве [redhat](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux).

в нём функции пакетного менеджера по умолчанию выполняет программа [yum](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Yum/ru).

если у вас инструкции только для *debian-осно́вных* дистрибутивов (где пакетными менеджерами служат программы *apt**), то, возможно, проще пересоздать виртуальную машину с указанием нужного дистрибутива (подозреваю, что скорее всего это *debian-осно́вный* дистрибутив *ubuntu*).

Comment: Как бы разобраться, как это сделать.

Comment: @RadoDuoistin, если вы не нашл в документации, как удалять и создавать виртуальные машины с нужными параметрами, то , возможно, имеет смысл задать новый вопрос с помощью одноимённой кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.